# AS3: How do I save out the data from a datagrid into a line-by-line text file?

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, air, text-files, save

I've got a datagrid populated with text file that has line-by-line words(ie. one per line). The datagrid has 5 columns. Every 5 words out of the text file is put in a new row. The datagrid can then be added to or removed from. How would I go about rewriting the text file using all the values in the datagrid?

This is how the datagrid gets populated. How can I go through the entire datagrid cell for cell and rewrite the data in the text file?

```
var loadFavourites: URLLoader = new URLLoader();;
var arFavourites = new Array();

loadFavourites.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadedFavourites);
loadFavourites.load(new URLRequest("lists/Favourites.txt"));

function onLoadedFavourites(event:Event):void
{
    arFavourites = event.target.data.split("\r\n");

    for (var i:int = 0; i <= arFavourites.length; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0 && i % 5 == 0)
        {
            dg.addItem({Place: arFavourites[i-5],Subject:arFavourites[i-4],Object:arFavourites[i-3],Feeling:arFavourites[i-2],Action:arFavourites[i-1]});

        }
    }
}
```

Add Record:

```
var i:int=0;
    var tPlace = mc_places.mc_places_text.txtPlaces.text;
    var tSubject = mc_subject.mc_subject_text.txtSubject.text;
    var tObject = mc_object.mc_object_text.txtObject.text;
    var tFeeling = mc_feeling.mc_feeling_text.txtFeeling.text;
    var tAction = mc_action.mc_action_text.txtAction.text;
    arFavourites[FavCount+1]=tPlace;
    arFavourites[FavCount+2]=tSubject;
    arFavourites[FavCount+3]=tObject;
    arFavourites[FavCount+4]=tFeeling;
    arFavourites[FavCount+5]=tAction;
    dg.addItem({Place: arFavourites[FavCount+1],Subject:arFavourites[FavCount+2],Object:arFavourites[FavCount+3],Feeling:arFavourites[FavCount+4],Action:arFavourites[FavCount+5]});
    dg.scrollToIndex(dg.length-1);
    FavCount=FavCount+5;
    for (i=0; i<arFavourites.length; i++) {
                trace(arFavourites[i]);
            }
```

Remove Record:

```
var k:int;
    var i:int;
    trace("Selected Index: " + dg.selectedIndex);
    if (dg.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    for (k=0; k<dg.length; k++) {
        if (dg.isItemSelected(dg.getItemAt(k))) {
            for (i=0; i<arFavourites.length; i++) {
                if (arFavourites[i] == dg.getItemAt(k)[1]) {
                    arFavourites.splice(i,1);
                    }
                if (arFavourites[i] == dg.getItemAt(k)[2]) {
                    arFavourites.splice(i,1);
                    }
                if (arFavourites[i] == dg.getItemAt(k)[3]) {
                    arFavourites.splice(i,1);
                    }
                if (arFavourites[i] == dg.getItemAt(k)[4]) {
                    arFavourites.splice(i,1);
                    }
                if (arFavourites[i] == dg.getItemAt(k)[5]) {
                    arFavourites.splice(i,1);
                    }
            }
            dg.removeItemAt(k);
            dg.scrollToIndex(k);
            dg.clearSelection();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to post any code on how you access the text file or populate the `DataGrid`? Also, is this an AIR app or just a SWF?

Comment: I hope that helps :) oh and it's an air app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what I would do is basically just the reverse. First you'd get the values of the `DataGrid` and put them back in an `Array` in the same order as before:

```
var newFavArray:Array = new Array();

for (var i:int = 1; i <= dg.length; i++)
{
    newFavourites[i * 5 - 5] = dg.getItemAt(i - 1).Place;
    newFavourites[i * 5 - 4] = dg.getItemAt(i - 1).Subject;
    newFavourites[i * 5 - 3] = dg.getItemAt(i - 1).Object;
    newFavourites[i * 5 - 2] = dg.getItemAt(i - 1).Feeling;
    newFavourites[i * 5 - 1] = dg.getItemAt(i - 1).Action;
}
```

(I whipped this up fairly quick, if you can find a better way of using `i` to access the `Array` and the `DataGrid` feel free to use it.)

Then you convert it to a `String`:

```
var newFavString:String = newFavArray.join("\r\n");
```

And then finally save it to the file however you want (overwriting the old values of course). Since it's an AIR app, it's best to use the `File` and `FileStream` classes for this:

```
var favFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("lists/Favourites.txt");
var favStream:FileStream = new FileStream();

favStream.open(favFile, FileMode.WRITE);
favStream.writeUTFBytes(newFavString);
favStream.close();
```

I'm not sure what your workflow is but personally I'd put all of this in a function:

```
function saveFavourites():void
{
    var newFavArray:Array = new Array();

    for (var i:int = 1; i <= dg.length; i++)
    {
        newFavArray[i * 5 - 5] = dg.getItemAt(i - 1).Place;
        newFavArray[i * 5 - 4] = dg.getItemAt(i - 1).Subject;
        newFavArray[i * 5 - 3] = dg.getItemAt(i - 1).Object;
        newFavArray[i * 5 - 2] = dg.getItemAt(i - 1).Feeling;
        newFavArray[i * 5 - 1] = dg.getItemAt(i - 1).Action;
    }

    var newFavString:String = newFavArray.join("\r\n");

    var favFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("lists/Favourites.txt");
    var favStream:FileStream = new FileStream();

    favStream.open(favFile, FileMode.WRITE);
    favStream.writeUTFBytes(newFavString);
    favStream.close();
}
```

which you can run whenever you want to.

If you haven't used `File` and `FileStream` before, it'd be worth it to check them out and see how they work. They're only available in AIR but they're much better and superior to `URLRequest` and `URLLoader`. You may also want to use them to load your file. They are only useful for local files though, if the file is online or something then I'm sure `URLLoader` is fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was working on something just like this. (Ie. Using the array as the main source). See above for the remove record and add record function. I would also like to know, how would I separate the values that go back into the text file to one-per-line?

Comment: I got this error when trying to write to the textfile: `SecurityError: fileWriteResource
 at flash.filesystem::FileStream/open()
 at TheIdeaFactoryv1_1_fla::MainTimeline/another()[TheIdeaFactoryv1_1_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:292]` which is at this line `favStream.open(favFile, FileMode.WRITE);`

Comment: Ok I did some more research and found that there is a restriction on writing to the application folder (Ie. /lists/Favourites.txt). I changed `var favFile:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("lists/Favourites.txt");` to `var favFile:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("lists/Favourites.txt");` and tested it on my iOS device and nothing.. Not working.. Please could you help me find a solution.

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot about that restriction (it appears to work when using `browseForSave` though). For configuration files and such, which I'm assuming Favourites.txt is, you should use `File.applicationStorageDirectory` instead. It's basically your application's "AppData" folder. I've never developed for iOS before, but it hopefully it should work (either way it's much better to use than `File.documentsDirectory`).

Comment: Also changed `applicationDirectory` to `applicationStorageDirectory` in the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work.. I tried userDirectory and that works on my PC but not on my iPad and applicationStorageDirectory doesnt work on either.. There has to be something that works..

Comment: I figured it out ^_^ The file didn't get created unless I told it to WRITE if there was no existing file and then READ. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Huh, strange. Good job on getting that sorted though, sorry that I couldn't help with it. Glad I could help with the rest though.